# hacer merge a master Git- Bitbucket

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Tengo una duda .

Resulta que en donde trabajo, he terminado dos de mis Sprints que se me asignaron pero tengo una duda.

La persona encargada de hacer los Merge a master me comentó que hay un conflicto en mis archivos

Resulta que estuve trabajando con Vue, entonces al hacer el npm run production se regeneran esos archivos de nuevo.

y en el App.js agregue mis componentes resulta que alguien más subió un cambió lo cual  modificamos el mismo archivo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo más archivos que están chocando con la versión de master

pero me dijo que haga un Pull Del master. pero ... ¿Cómo o por que no entiendo eso se que me va actualizar mis nuevos cambios del MAster, pero mis cambios actuales que subí desd otra rama y lo cual busco el merge, en fin .por ejemplo

el app.js sabemos que hay dos archivos diferentes por el npm run production o que hago?

Comment: Sientate a resolver el conflicto (los conflictos son parte del día a día de los desarrolladores). Este es un gran tema en si mismo.... **autopromoción**: tengo una guía al respecto. Si tienes el tiempo, pues dale: http://www.ezconflict.com/es/ (sin tracking, sin cookies).

Comment: Tengo una pregunta: ese archivo se genera como parte del proceso de construcción del proyecto? O es un archivo que hay que mantener manualmente?

Comment: @eftshift0 el npm run production se se generan los archivos  según los nuevos componentes que haya Creado en mi carpeta app.js con ello al hacer npm run production pasan a pesar menos.  igual tengo otros archivos que están chocando pero me dice que haga git pull rama master y luego los suba. eso no se borrara?

Answer (score 1):

Ok.... la regla *general* es **no incluir en control de versiones los archivos que se generan como parte de la construcción del proyecto**.

Ahora bien, para salir del paso: Si ese archivo se construye, no le pares por ahora.... resuelve los otros conflictos de los archivos para que puedas entonces **construir el proyecto**. Cuando lo construyas, entonces agrega *este* archivo de la pregunta (que ya estaría arreglado como parte del proceso de construcción).

Y ya como corolario: ese archivo no debió ser agregado a git. Si les es posible, sáquenlo (e ignórenlo). No lo pongo como una **obligación** porque cada situación es diferente... pero en general, si el archivo se **construye**, no debe entrar en control de versiones, como decía al comienzo.